TanStack query with react check if an object is in the cache by its id
I have a use case where I need to call a paged api like;
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=4&name=ric
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=5&name=ric
when we make those queries with react-query, each call will add its data to cache with different cacheKey AFAIK.
What I need is to be able to check if an object is already created in the cache, by its id maybe, in any one of that paged query calls?

There certainly are ways to do this using queryClient.getQueryData() or  queryClient.getQueryState(), but what is the reason you need to check this? Doing so seems to be an anti-pattern.

 const ['key', { page, name }] = queryKey;
  const { data } = await axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character`, {
    params: { page, name },
  });

Create your query like this, when the page and name state changes, react-query will automatically refetch and assign the new values, overriding the existing values to the same query key
